# Java EE: how to access local EJB from web module?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, javabeans, code-injection

I have created a local EJB that I want to access from a web module in the same VM. My code looks like this:

```
@EJB
private UserBeanLocal userBean;

public UsuarioManagedBean() {
     InitialContext c = new InitialContext();
     userBean = (UserBeanLocal) c.lookup("java:global/UsersApp/Users-ejb/UserBean!biz.users.beans.UserBeanLocal");
}

public List<User> getUsers() {
    users = this.userBean.listUsers();
    return users;
}
```

And this works fine. However, somebody told me that I don't need to do a lookup if I'm working with a local bean, I only need to make an injection like this:

```
@EJB
private UserBeanLocal userBean;

public UsuarioManagedBean() {

}

public List<User> getUsers() {
    users = this.userBean.listUsers();
    return users;
}
```

But if I try this I get a null exception on this.userBean.
The person who advised me works with JBoss and I'm using glassfish. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What version of JEE and Glassfish are u using? JEE5 supports dependency injection(DI), so if you are using a older version, it wouldnt work. Same with Jboss, there are certain restrictions in which DI would not work in jboss-4.2.3, but would be fine in jboss 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @EJB annotation only works with application-server controlled classes like servlets, mdbs, other ejbs.
I'm guessing that UsuarioManagedBean is a pojo and hence the NPE because the resource never gets injected.

Answer (score 1):

@Lucia looks like UsuarioManagedBean is a POJO. @Kal is right. You cannot inject ejb into a pojo. 
If you really want to inject into a pojo consider using CDI.

Using CDI your code will look as below

`@Inject private UserBeanLocal userBean;`

Please publish more details like jvm version, Glassfish version etc..

Comment: Thanks Kiran, in fact UsuarioManagedBean is a pojo.