# Getting null while using ejb session in web pojo class

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have ejb session class `testImpl` and its interface `testLocal`. I am using `testLocal` in my `managedBean` but Now I need to to use `testLocal` in my simple java class like `pojo`.

I went following question :

- [Java EE: how to access local EJB from web module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488270/java-ee-how-to-access-local-ejb-from-web-module)

and so on. But could not get my requirement.

My question is:

1. Can I access (**use**) ejb session classes in my simple java class which is in **web-module** or not ? and
2. If yes, then what is the procedure ?

**Note:** I am using **EE5**

Answer (score 1):

Two way you can access ejb session bean.

1. Using JNDI lookup and
2. Using Dependency Injection

For details, go through to this [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/ejb-intro004.htm#GIPJF).